# C# Create high score text file and reorder the results

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create  a text file containing the players' scores of a hangman game. The structure of the text file should follow the order: number. name score (e.g. 1. Helen 2500). I tried to split the line so that I can introduce the data into a specific array for name and score so that I can compare the results and reorder them (the numbers remain the same: 1, 2, 3, etc.) but it doesn't work. I don't get errors but the building stops at this function because of an incorrect use of the array v[]. What do you suggest me to do to make it work?

[code]

```
private void New_Score(int score)
        {
            int k=0, i;
            char[] sep = new char[] { ' ', '\n', '.' };
            string line, aux1, aux2;
            string n=null, s=null;
            n = textBox1.Text;
            s = Convert.ToString(score);
            string[] part=null, nr=null, name=null, result=null;
            file_path = @"D:\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\WindowsApplication2\WindowsApplication2\Resources\HighScore.txt";
            StreamReader f = new StreamReader(file_path);

            while ((line = f.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                part = null;
                v = null;
                part = line.Split(sep);
                i=0;
                foreach(string c in part)
                {
                    v[i]= c;
                    i++;
                }
                nr[k] = v[0];
                name[k] = v[1];
                result[k] = v[2];
            }

            for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
                if (string.CompareOrdinal(s,result[i]) == 1)
                {
                    aux1 = s;
                    s = result[i];
                    result[i] = aux1;

                    aux2 = n;
                    n = name[i];
                    name[i] = aux2;
                }

            for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                line = nr[i] + ". " + name[i] + " " + result[i] + "\n";
                File.WriteAllText(file_path, line);
            }
        }
```

[/code]

Comment: Do you *need* the text file to be in that format? It would be simpler to use XML, for example - no need to manually split etc. I'd also *strongly* suggest having a single class to represent a result, rather than trying to sort three arrays together.

Comment: No, I don't absolutely need a text file, but I didn't know I could simplify it by using XML. I'm not used to c#

Thank you, Jon Skeet! I'll try it this way

Comment: I'd recomend you to avoid hardcoding file name in your program :) Use smth like `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

Comment: Thank you for this point, Aleksej Vasinov! :)

Answer (score 4):

I would personally abstract the code a bit more, but if you don't want to add any more classes or really do anything outside of the method, here's what I'd do:

- Parse high scores in as a `List<Tuple<int, string, int>>`
- Add the new score
- Use either `list.Sort()` or LINQ to sort the list
- Write the list out to the file.

It's a lot cleaner and way more readable than what you have in the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to store number, line position can serve to that purpose. Even better would be serialize List with score objects to for example XML (if you want to keep human readable score file), to avoid line parsing. But if you want to store to plain text here is a simple example :

```
private void New_Score(int score, string name)
{
  string filename = "scores.txt";
  List<string> scoreList;
  if (File.Exists(filename))
    scoreList = File.ReadAllLines(filename).ToList();
  else
    scoreList = new List<string>();
  scoreList.Add(name + " " + score.ToString());
  var sortedScoreList = scoreList.OrderByDescending(ss => int.Parse(ss.Substring(ss.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1)));
  File.WriteAllLines(filename, sortedScoreList.ToArray());
}
```

And later when displaying results add order number in front, something like this:

```
  int xx = 1;
  List<string> scoreList = File.ReadAllLines(filename).ToList();
  foreach (string oneScore in scoreList)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(xx.ToString() + ". " + oneScore);
    xx++;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact this goes entirely against the [saying about fishing and eating](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day._Teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime) which I strongly support, I took the liberty  of making a few improvements by completely rewriting your code.

First of all, I got rid of storing the position of the player in the text file. This isn't efficient, since when you add a player with the highest score (rendering him #1), you'll have to re-number everyone else that's present in the file at that point.

So the resulting file looks like this:

```
Foo 123 
Qux 714 
Bar 456 
Baz 999
```

The `main()` method looks like this:

```
var scores = ReadScoresFromFile("Highscores.txt");

scores.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));

Console.ReadKey();
```

Then there's the `Highscore` class:

```
class Highscore
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public Highscore(String data)
    {
        var d = data.Split(' ');

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data) || d.Length < 2)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid high score string", "data");

        this.Name = d[0];

        int num;
        if (int.TryParse(d[1], out num))
        {
            this.Score = num;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid score", "data");
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}. {1}: {2}", this.Position, this.Name, this.Score);
    }
}
```

You see a Highscore populates itself based on the line from the Highscore file it's fed. I populate the list of scores using this method:

```
static List<Highscore> ReadScoresFromFile(String path)
{
    var scores = new List<Highscore>();

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        String line;
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                scores.Add(new Highscore(line));
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid score at line \"{0}\": {1}", line, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    return SortAndPositionHighscores(scores);
}
```

And finally some sorting and position assigment:

```
static List<Highscore> SortAndPositionHighscores(List<Highscore> scores)
{
    scores = scores.OrderByDescending(s => s.Score).ToList();

    int pos = 1;

    scores.ForEach(s => s.Position = pos++);

    return scores.ToList();
}
```

Resulting in:

```
1. Baz: 999
2. Qux: 714
3. Bar: 456
4. Foo: 123
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a complicated way to store a simple list of high scores. Why don't you try the following.

Define a simple object to hold a player's score.

```
[Serializable]
public class HighScore
{
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }

    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure you mark it with the [[Serializable]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) attribute.

Let's quickly create a list of high scores for a couple of players.

```
var highScores = new List<HighScore>()
{
    new HighScore { PlayerName = "Helen", Score = 1000 },
    new HighScore { PlayerName = "Christophe", Score = 2000 },
    new HighScore { PlayerName = "Ruben", Score = 3000 },
    new HighScore { PlayerName = "John", Score = 4000 },
    new HighScore { PlayerName = "The Last Starfighter", Score = 5000 }
};
```

Now you can use the [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) to serialize the scores and save them to a local file.

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\scores.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(fileStream, highScores);
}
```

Later you can load the high scores from this files in a similar manner.

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\scores.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    highScores = (List<HighScore>) formatter.Deserialize(fileStream);
}
```

If you want to sort them you can implement the [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) interface on the HighScore type.

```
[Serializable]
public class HighScore : IComparable
{
    //...

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        var otherScore = (HighScore) obj;
        if (Score == otherScore.Score)            
            return 0;            

        if (Score < otherScore.Score)            
            return 1;            

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Now you can just call the Sort(...) on your generic List collection.

```
highScores.Sort();
```

And voila the scores are sorted in a descending order.

```
foreach(var score in highScores)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1} points", score.PlayerName, score.Score));
}
```

Or even more simple, just use LINQ to sort the high scores.

```
var sortedScores = highScores.OrderByDescending(s => s.Score).ToList();
```